# Flutter forEach() - Error: This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the plugin `just_audio: ^0.7.4` from https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio. This plugin works with a system of playlist, we define a playlist this way (example with 3 songs):

```
    final _playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: [
      AudioSource.uri(
        Uri.parse('AUDIO_LINK_1'),
        tag: AudioMetadata(
          title: 'TITLE',
          album: 'ALBUM',
        ),
      ),
      AudioSource.uri(
        Uri.parse('AUDIO_LINK_2'),
        tag: AudioMetadata(
          title: 'TITLE',
          album: 'ALBUM',
        ),
      ),
      AudioSource.uri(
        Uri.parse('AUDIO_LINK_3'),
        tag: AudioMetadata(
          title: 'TITLE',
          album: 'ALBUM',
        ),
      ),
    ]);
```

I'm trying to take audio links from Firebase with this code:

```
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('languages/${widget.languageId}/contents_path')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(
              'towns/${widget.townId}/beacons/${widget.beaconId}/${event.docs[0]['path']}')
          .snapshots()
          .listen((event) async {
        final _playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: [
          event.docs.forEach((element) { // Error here
            AudioSource.uri(
              Uri.parse(element['audio']),
              tag: AudioMetadata(
                title: element['title'],
                album: widget.album,
              ),
            );
          })
        ]);
```

But I got an error at `forEach`:

> This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.
> Try checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void.

Have you an idea what is going wrong here and what I have to change? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Write like `(element) => { ......}` . See the arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `forEach`. `forEach` returns a `void`. Remove `[]` too otherwise you need to use the spread operator. Add `async-await` wherever necessary because I can see `listen` callback is `async`.

```dart
final _playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(
  children: event.docs.map(
    (element) {
      return AudioSource.uri(
        Uri.parse(element['audio']),
        tag: AudioMetadata(
          title: element['title'],
          album: widget.album,
        ),
      );
    },
  ).toList(),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use map instead of forEach

```
final _playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: 
          event.docs.map((element) { 
          return   AudioSource.uri(
              Uri.parse(element['audio']),
              tag: AudioMetadata(
                title: element['title'],
                album: widget.album,
              ),
            );
          }).toList()
        );
```